# Get value APP_SECRET to controller in Symfony 4

Tags: php, symfony

Is it posible to get value from `APP_SECRET` and use it in controller in Symfony 4?

Comment: try `getenv('APP_SECRET ');`

Comment: If you just copy/pasted that code, remove the extra space in it, @delifer.

Comment: The proper way would to inject it into the controller's constructor just like any other parameter.  Avoid using getenv in a Symfony app.

Comment: Please share more details - what have you tried so far, what did not work?

Answer (score 4):

Inject it into controller using `%env(APP_SECRET)%` syntax in services.yaml

```
services:
    App\Controller\DefaultController:
        class: 'App\Controller\DefaultController'
        arguments: ['%env(APP_SECRET)%']
```

Reference: https://symfony.com/doc/current/configuration/external_parameters.html

You may also bind this argument globally, so you don't have to make a service definition specifically for it:

```
services:
    _defaults:
        bind:
            $appSecret: '%env(APP_SECRET)%'
```

Then in your controller's constructor you may inject it using the same name:

```
class DefaultController
{
    public function __construct($appSecret)
    {
    }
}
```

Reference: https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container.html#binding-arguments-by-name-or-type

Answer (score -1):

### Symfony 4

For me worked `$_ENV['APP_SECRET']`.

More can be found at https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dotenv.html

Comment: Using the usual ways of injecting parameters, like answered by MakG, should be used. This helps to make your application more solid for testability

Comment: For me MakG solution didn't work, and this is acceptable solution according to official symfony docs https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dotenv.html